# Connect with Cassandra Cluster using thrift

Tags: cassandra, thrift

I am using Cassandra 1.2.8 with Thrift API currently i am working remotely with only my local server. But i need to connect it with a cluster on my production servers. I can easily connect with cluster using Hector API but i have done most of my development using Thrift so i don't want to shift to Hector.
with Thrift i am connecting to a server with this code

```
    TTransport tr = new TFramedTransport(new TSocket("10.11.11.111", 9160));
    TProtocol proto = new TBinaryProtocol(tr, true, true);
    Cassandra.Client client = new Cassandra.Client(proto);
    tr.open();
```

Please guide me how to do this

Thanks

Comment: And what's the problem when you try to connect to the production server?

Comment: @DirkLachowski with one ip (node) it is connecting but i want a cluster of node
Thanks for replaying

Comment: I've written Cassandra Thrift clients before and can *strongly* recommend that you use a client library instead. Hector is good, as is the DataStax java driver if you want to move to CQL.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect with one machine from the cluster, you are automatically connected to the whole cluster. The cluster manages the distribution etc. of the data transparently to your application,  you need just one server to talk to, and it can be any one. It's really that simple.

Comment: You will need to connect to multiple servers though (ideally all). Otherwise your throughput is limited to what one node can handle and if that node fails, your client goes offline.

Comment: You may need. But you don't have to, technically.

Comment: Technically, you don't need to. But in production you will have an outage and unscalable system if you don't.